# How do I progress the Companions questline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started a quest for the companions on xbox 360 and it says to intimidate Captain Aldis in Solitude, but I've already completed the Stormcloak line so he doesnt spawn. Any fixes?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in in the [UESP wiki page for Captain Aldis](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Captain_Aldis#Bugs), if you side with the Stormcloaks and finish the quest "Battle for Solitude" in the civil war questline, Captain Aldis will no longer be available in-game. Quest markers that should point to him will instead point to the ground where he normally stands. This is a known bug, and there is no known fix for console players.

Comment: Is there a way to reset it?

Comment: @JulianBayer On 360, there is no way to reset it other than reloading a save prior to the completion of "Battle for Solitude".

Comment: Damn that would put me back a while

Comment: @JulianBayer Wish I had better news for you. The civil war questline causes all sorts of issues like this, so for future playthroughs, I would recommend you put it off until you're done with everything else.

Comment: @JulianBayer Do you have a save from before you picked up the Companions' quest instead?  You might be able to test if fast-travelling away and/or completing a different radiant quest changes who you get given.